# How to detect all cursor movements and key presses on a Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard, mouse

What is the best method to detect all cursor movements and key presses on a Mac using objective-c on OSX Lion?

Comment: What do you mean all? All in the application or all across the entire system?

Comment: @Davyd, all in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by installing an event monitor

```
- (void)monitorEvents
{
    // Monitor all events
    NSUInteger eventMasks =  NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSRightMouseDownMask | NSMouseMovedMask | NSScrollWheelMask | NSKeyDownMask | NSMouseMovedMask | NSEventTypeBeginGesture | NSEventTypeEndGesture;

    eventMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:eventMasks handler:^(NSEvent *incomingEvent) 
    {
        NSEvent *result = incomingEvent;

        return result;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would subclass `NSApplication` and override the `-sendEvent:` method.